# socketio broadcast msg when I use it inside EventEmitter

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have web socket server and http server, and I want to tell socketio server to emit a msg to the client only if an event was emitted using EventEmitter Class, the problem is when I open 2 tabs in browser I noticed that the event was send to all users (broadcasting)

here is the both servers:

```
const server = require('http').createServer(handler)
    , io = require('socket.io')(server)
    , url = require('url')
    , fs = require('fs')
    , EventEmitter = require('events')
    , emitter = new EventEmitter();

server.listen(3000);

function handler(req, res) {

    var route = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    if (route === '/') {
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/index.html');
        stream.pipe(res);
    } else if (route === '/testSocket') {
        var stream = fs.createReadStream(__dirname + '/test.html');
        stream.pipe(res);
        // emit event after 5s, the handler is inside socketio server
        setTimeout( function() {
            emitter.emit('fromEmitterToSocketServer', 'Msg');
        }, 5000);
    } else {
        res.writeHead(404, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
        res.end('404');
    }

}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {

    // handle event and then send data to the user
    emitter.on('fromEmitterToSocketServer', function(data) {

        // here I noticed that socketio emit the event to all users
        socket.emit('fromSocketServerToClient', data); 

    });

});
```

Index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Index</h1>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

        var socket = io('//localhost:3000');

        socket.on('fromSocketServerToClient', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

test.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Test socketIO</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Test socketIO</h1>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.3/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

        var socket = io('//localhost:3000');

        socket.on('fromSocketServerToClient', function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If I open two tabs and go to http://localhost:3000 and http://localhost:3000/testSocket I figure out that the msg is logged into the both of them

Thanks

Comment: Isn't EventEmitter redundant? Socket.io already uses EventEmitter. You can achieve the same goal with less code by using namespaces, see https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: You're telling it to do so.  Each time a client connects (io.on('connection'...) you add a listener to the event emitter (emitter.on('fromSocketServerToClient'...)) which then sends a message across that connection (socket.on('fromSocketServerToClient'...)).  Therefore, every time the emitter fires an event, every client will receive one as well.  Can you describe the behavior you're actually looking for?

Comment: actually i'm looking for passing some data from httpServer to socketio server that's why I use eventEmitter